# Creating a grid of obj objects in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a 10 X 10 grid of a chair obj file in three.js. I have a function that will add a chair to the scene. However, when I try to return the object to a looping function to create more of them, I am told that "undefined is not an object. It doesn't seem to be saving the object that it is supposed to return. Here is what I have.

```
function getChair(){
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    loader.load(‘assets/models/theatreChair.obj’, function (object) {
        var colorMap = textureLoader.load(‘assets/textures/chairDiffuseColor.png’);
        var bumpMap = textureLoader.load(‘assets/textures/chairBumpTextures.png’);
        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial(‘rgb(255,255,255)’);

        object.traverse(function(child) {

            child.material = faceMaterial;
            faceMaterial.roughness = 1;
            faceMaterial.map = colorMap;
            faceMaterial.bumpMap = bumpMap;
            faceMaterial.roughnessMap = bumpMap;
            faceMaterial.metalness = 0;
            faceMaterial.bumpScale = 0.1;
        });
        // scene.add(object) -- This works. It adds a chair at 0,0,0. Use scroll wheel to see it.
        return object; // Should return the chair object, right?
    });
}

function getChairGrid(amount, seperationMultiplier){
   var group = new THREE.Group();

   for (var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
       var obj = getChair();
       obj.position.x = i * seperationMultiplier; // Fails here. “undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘obj.position’)”
       obj.position.y = obj.geometry.parameters.height/2;
       group.add(obj);
       for (var j = 1; j<amount; j++){
           var obj = getChair();
           obj.position.x = i * seperationMultiplier;
           obj.position.y = obj.geometry.parameters.height/2;
           obj.position.z = j * seperationMultiplier;
           group.add(obj);

       }
   }

   group.position.x = -(seperationMultiplier * (amount-1))/2;
   group.position.z = -(seperationMultiplier * (amount-1))/2;

   return group;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create a clone or instance of 1 object rather than loading it multiple times?

Comment: `loader.load()` is asynchronous. That is why you specified a callback function.

Comment: Yes. I should be creating a clone of the object instead of recreating it. However, if I do var myObject = getChair() and then log myObject in the console. It says it is undefined. That's the part I am not understanding. What can I not get the getChair function to give me a complete object even though it can add one to the scene?

Comment: Each time you are calling `getChair()` it is trying to load the object again & it is an async process.You can not return the object until it is loaded completely. And you are not returning any object from `getChair()`. I think what you need to do is to save the object in a global variable or trigger a function from `loader.load()` when object loading is complete.